# AddThis share button not working

Tags: facebook-social-plugins, addthis

I am trying to integrate addthis share button on website so that it can show me count next to the button but count is always 0 irrespect of what account you use it for.

```
    <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_pill_combo">
        <a class="addthis_button_tweet" tw:count="horizontal"></a>
        <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like"></a>
        <a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
    </div>

    <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
    <script type="text/javascript">    var addthis_config = { "data_track_addressbar": false };</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-xxxxxxxx"></script>
```

I want something like [this example](http://www.addthis.com/blog/2013/01/30/introducing-individual-share-counts/#.UiwVrH_4K00)

Is there a way we can facebook page and twitter account to this as i am not able to work using PubID

Answer (score -1):

make sure to use Jquery Js files on your page